# strange right scroll of 15 px on one particular page - css issue

Tags: html, css, scroll

Apologies, but I can't create a JSFiddle for this issue.

I have a site with a slight (15px or so) right scroll that occurs.

It only shows on one particle page:

http://www.mylondonhome.com/property-for-sale/house-for-sale/moncorvo-close-knightsbridge-london-sw7/2434

I'm sure I have sone bad CSS some where, but I have been staring at it for far too long.

Any CSS gurus see the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the `body {width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden}` and `html {width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden !important}`

**//EDIT**

you also need to remove this:

```
.mm-page {
    margin: 0;
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

and add `position relative` to `.mm-page` instead!

Comment: This is great... only problem it causes is for my header & breadcrumb to be fixed under the vertical scroll. Did you get the same issue?

Comment: edited. you should not use top, left etc values without a positioning!

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the page with Chrome, it shows that the problem is in your section called "section-featured". The div there with the class "row" has a negative margin of 15px. Disabling this in the inspector removes the right scroll.

```
<section class="section-featured">
   <div class="row"> <!-- This div has a margin of -15px -->
```